# laravel-5.8::The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to update data but it shows error "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

route:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('category','CategoryController'); 
});
```

controller:

```
public function edit(Category $category) 
{
    $categories = Category::findOrFail($category->id); 

    return view('admin.category.edit', compact('categories')); 
} 

public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $request->validate([
        'category_name'         => 'required|unique:categories',
        'category_description'  => 'required',
        'category_slug'         => 'required',
        'category_image'        => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $category = Category::find($category->id);
    $category->category_name = $request->category_name;
    $category->category_description = $request->category_description;
    $category->category_slug = $request->category_slug;
    $path = $request->file('category_image');
    $image = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images'), $image);
    $category->category_image = $image;
    $category->save();

    return redirect('admin.category.index')->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Category has been updated successfully');
```

blade file:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.category.update', $category->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
```

Comment: do you have update method within your CategoryController?

Comment: i show u the updated method in question

Comment: your code is correct, try restarting your server

Comment: i restart every thing now it says: Undefined variable: category at index

Comment: Try sending through PUT

Comment: same result with put

Comment: how do you display the edit form for edit the category? with edit method ?

Comment: {{ route('admin.category.edit', $category->id) }}

Comment: please update your controller code with the edit method, I guess that you are missing something

Comment: public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        $categories = Category::findOrFail($category->id);
        return view('admin.category.edit', compact('categories'));
    }

Comment: Why are you doing `$category = Category::find($category->id);`?? `$category` already is the loaded instance of the `Category` you want.  https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: its not resolving i dont know what should i khow

Comment: in your blad file.. just remove patch so it will let you post data or else.. use patch method and share model id detail with route in form action

Comment: thnx i resolve it but its not going back after edit and still remains on edit page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $_val = request()->validate([
        'category_name'         => 'required|unique:categories',
        'category_description'  => 'required',
        'category_slug'         => 'required',
        'category_image'        => 'required|image',
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('category_image');
    $image = $path->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->move(public_path('images/backend_images/category_images'), $image);
    $_val['category_image'] = $image;

    $category = Category::find($request->id);
    $category->update($_val);


    return redirect('admin.category.index')->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Category has been updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: still same result

Comment: try on your route: `Route::resource('category','CategoryController')->name('category.update');` and on your form action `{{ route('category.update', $category->id) }}`